# Implementing Class Table Inheritance in Loopback

Tags: javascript, inheritance, loopbackjs

I'm trying to implement sub-classing in Loopback models, where I have a parent table with common fields and tables that are children of the parent table with specific fields.

A practical example:

#### `Customer`

*A model with fields that apply for both persons and organisations*

- `internal_id`
- `created`

#### `Person`

*A model with only person-specific fields*

- `first_name`
- `last_name`

#### `Organisation`

*A model with only organisation-specific fields*

- `registration_number`
- `trade_name`

---

So basically `Person` inherits from `Customer` and `Organisation` inherits from `Customer` as well.

I've followed this guide for [Extending Models](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Customizing+models) to create `Person` and `Organisation` models *based* on the `Customer` model

However when I create a `Person`, i.e via `POST` at `http://0.0.0:3000/persons`, he is created in `Person` table but not on `Customer` table.

I assumed that when if I extend a model based on another model, when saving the extendee model it also saves the common fields into the parent model.

This doesn't seem to be the case. How can I achieve this in Loopback?

---

In case they are needed here are the models jsons:

#### `customer.json`

```
{
  "name": "Organisation",
  "plural": "Organisations",
  "base": "Customer",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "registration_number": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "trade_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

#### `person.json`

```
{
  "name": "Person",
  "plural": "Persons",
  "base": "Customer",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "first_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "last_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

#### `organisation.json`

```
{
  "name": "Organisation",
  "plural": "Organisations",
  "base": "Customer",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "registration_number": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "trade_name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loopback doesn't provide this type of inheritance. Models are merely templates, and extending a model just create a new template with properties/methods obtained from the inherited model.

I understand that you want to abstract whether a customer is a person or an organization.This looks like a typical use-case for [polymorphic relations](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Polymorphic+relations). Polymorphic relations let you relate one model to several other models.

Here is how I would structure the application:

In `customer.js`

```
{
  "name": "Customer",
  // ...
  "relations": {
    "customerable": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "polymorphic": true
    }
  }, // ...
}
```

In `person.js`

```
{
  "name": "Person",
  // ...
  "relations": {
    "customer": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Customer",
      "polymorphic": {"as": "customerable", "discriminator": "person"}
    }
  }, // ...
}
```

In `organization.js`

```
{
  "name": "Organization",
  // ...
  "relations": {
    "orders": {
      "type": "hasOne",
      "model": "Customer",
      "polymorphic": {"as": "customerable", "discriminator": "organization"} 
    }
  }, // ...
}
```

I used [this example](https://gist.github.com/fabien/ccce7f1de399c0227ce6) because the loopback doc is not very clear

Comment: Thanks - I don't have an `Order` model - did you mean `Customer`?

Comment: No, I really meant `Orders` to store your orders, sales. IMO you should drop the customer model since it represents more a relation between an order and a client.

Comment: `IMO you should drop the customer model since it represents more a relation between an order and a client` - What happens to fields that are common between a `Person` and an `Organisation` then? Duplicate them in each model? Also the Order model you have is confusing me - I don't and won't have Orders in any part of the system at all

Comment: I called the polymorphic relation `orderable`, but not a wise choice. Best name would actually be `customers`, because then could do a `GET api/Orders/customers` and get all person and orgs that passed an order. I will edit my answer

Comment: You can either duplicate them or build a specific model for storing them, then add a relation `Person` `hasOne` `CommonProps` and `Organisation` `hasOne` `CommonPros`.

Comment: I thought your system was meant to keep tracks of orders made by customers. In that case it made sense to have a polymorphic relation. But if you don't keep track of orders, I suspect you don't need to bother with inheritance at all. Could you detail more your goal ? Why do you need inheritance ?

Comment: Well, I've got 2 Similar entities, the Person and the Organisation - Those 2 will share a lot of common fields and *relations* with other tables. They need to be kept distinct (no way of having only Customer), because while they share a lot of stuff, in other cases they don't

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125076/discussion-between-nicholas-kyriakides-and-overdrivr).